# Matching nav buttons with header background

Tags: css, html

I've got a navigation in the header and the header got a gradient from left to right.
The navbar got an other background.
The navbuttons needs to be the same as the header background at that place.

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>button1</li>
            <li>button2</li>
            <li>button3</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

1. Header got gradient.
2. Nav got one color.
3. Li needs to be the same as header background on the same place.

Answer (score 3):

You could make the entire nav transparent and make use of solid borders on list elements.

## [*demo*](http://dabblet.com/gist/3906821)

You can use this with `border-radius` on the buttons or with an animated background for the header.

### Basic idea

Suppose you have a header structure like:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href=''>Products</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>Services</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>Technologies</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

- You give the header a certain background (CSS gradient, image,
  whatever) and make sure none of its children has a background.
- You set the padding and margins for `nav`, `ul` and `li` to be `0`.
- You set wide, solid borders on the `li` elements and you're done. You
  can then tweak this (see the demo).

Comment: @ana could you please choose any other tool like jsfiddle or codepen. dabblet doesn't work properly for many people

Comment: @JitendraVyas Well, I only have a really small laptop and it's really difficult for me to write code in tiny boxes. That's why I use CodePen or jsFiddle only when I need JavaScript for a demo or when I need to test something for IE8/7. In what circumstances doesn't Dabblet work properly? I'm on Win 7 and I don't have any kind of problems with this demo in any browser that supports CSS gradients or keyframe animations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to 'punch through' to the header background gradient in code alone. You will have to fake it by either:

a) Painstakingly recreating the gradient in the `<li>`'s so that it lines up with the background of the header. You should have fixed widths to the `<li>`'s if you go this route.

b) create a background image for the `<nav>` that is a solid color, but has holes punched out so you can see the gradient behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you might be able to use the same image as the header on the li's, but offset it to match the position of each li with regards to the header.

Of course this would require some client side scripting, and would not be pure css, and you have not stated if this would be an acceptable solution, so I'm throwing in my 2 cents.

Cheers

EDIT:

Here's a small proof of concept:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="offset.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>ALLO</li>
                    <li>ALLO</li>
                    <li>ALLO</li>
                    <li>ALLO</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>   
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background-image: url("gradient.png");
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-image: url("navbg.jpg");
    background-position: 0px 10px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 100px;
}

li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-image: url("gradient.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px; 
    background-origin: content-box;
}
```

Javascript (in file offset.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elems = $("li");
    $.each(elems, function(index, elem){
        var li = $(elem);
        var pos = li.position();
        var posString = -pos.left.toString() + "px " + -pos.top.toString() + "px"
        li.css("backgroundPosition", posString);

    });

});
```

Works in Chrome, FF and IE9

Hope this helps